# Mongoose Model.count() respond in number instead of object

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose

In my express server using Mongoose, I have the code below that I wish it can respond to the client with the number logged inside.

```
  api.post('/countCompletedTask', function(req, res) {
    Task.count({$and: [{taskProjectID: req.body.id}, {complete_date: {$ne: "Incomplete"}}]}, function(err, count) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(count); // it logs a number like 2 or 3, and I want this number sent to the client
      res.send(count);
    })
  })
```

However, in my client using AngularJS, when the controller receives it, it becomes an object. And here is my controller method that catches the number:

```
angular.module('projectCtrl', ['projectService'])

.controller('ProjectController', function(Project, Task, socketio, $filter) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.percentage = function(id) {
    var totalTasks = Task.countTotalTask(id);
    var completedTasks = Task.countCompletedTask(id);
    console.log(Task.countTotalTask(id) + " total"); // it returns an object
    console.log(Task.countCompletedTask(id) + " completed"); // it returns an object
    return 100 * (completedTasks / totalTasks);
  }
}
```

So I wonder is there anything wrong with the api or the controller? If not, then how should I get the number I need from the object?

Thanks for the help

Comment: The "object" that you get is a promise. An extremely helpful explanation can be found [here](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html)

Comment: That's actually what I've been doing. But the problem is I don't know how to extract the count from the object.